# Getting 500 internal server error when passing Json to MVC controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass 2 list string json to my controller and compare the changes.

Here is my model

```
public class PhongtreeView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller

```
public ActionResult SaveChanges(IEnumerable<PhongtreeView> InitTree,IEnumerable<PhongtreeView> UpdatedTree)
    {
        //Compare changes
        return View();
    }
```

My Ajax code

```
$("#SaveChanges").click(function () {
    getJson();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveChanges", "Phong")',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            JSonFirst: JSON.stringify(StartTreeJson),
            JSonFinal: JSON.stringify(UpdatedTreeJson)
        },
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                alertify.success(" Success");
                //window.location.reload();

            }
            else {
                alertify.error(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
```

But i always get the 500 internal error.If i remove the **contentType: "application/json"** it can run but it only pass null value to controller. Can someone tell me what's wrong ? Thank in advance.

Comment: It means your controller is throwing an exception (you have not shown any of the code, but `InitTree` and `UpdatedTree` will both be empty collections or `null`)

Comment: Model Binding is not going to work since the parameters that you post have different names from the specified in controller action. You need to rename  `JSonFirst` to `InitTree` and `JSonFinal` to `UpdatedTree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass 2 complex types to action method directly. The way to be done is shown below:

Create a class

```
public class Tree
{
    public List<PhongtreeView> InitTree { get; set;}
    public List<PhongtreeView> UpdatedTree { get; set;}
}
```

Your action method:

```
public ActionResult SaveChanges(IEnumerable<Tree> trees)
{
    //Compare changes
    return View();
}
```

In Js side, you need to set the data as follows:

```
var StartTreeJsonData = [{Id : 1, ParentId : 1},{Id : 2, ParentId : 2}];
var UpdatedTreeJsonData = [{Id : 10, ParentId : 10},{Id : 20, ParentId : 20}];

data: '{InitTree : StartTreeJsonData, UpdatedTree : UpdatedTreeJsonData}'
```

Comment: You **can** pass a hundred complex types to an action method if you want to!

Comment: Lets consider his scenario, can you suggest how to pass 2 complex  parameters to his action which has 2 complex type params?

Comment: Just as OP is currently doing (by including 2 parameters) although there is nothng wrongwith havindone model. OP's issue is that the format of the json data is wrong and therefore cannot be bound (your last snippet is almost correct, but it needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ {InitTree : StartTreeJsonData, UpdatedTree : UpdatedTreeJsonData }),`

Comment: Ok. will give it a try to pass multiple complex types. will keep you posted:)  Actually we can use single quote as i have done instead of stringify too. I have used this approach as well in my application, it works fine. Behind the hood stringify will convert the js object to json string. But even if we use single quote for the js object, the webapi will bind the model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i changed the data as you pointed out , the program compile fine and passing the right list count , but all the values are null ( all 2 json have the correct values ). Is there something wrong with json.net and guid ?

Comment: @TânNguyễnHuỳnh, There is nothing wrong with _json.net and guid_. If its not binding, its because the data your sending is not correct